# How to convert from String to XSDDatetime

Tags: java

For example: I have a string `"2018-03-15T15:52:57z"`
I am trying to convet to XSDDatetime.

```
XSDDatetime dt = new  XSDDatetime(string);
```

Comment: What is not working? What have you tried?

Comment: where does that class come from? i only found apache `jena`, but that class doesn't have constructor which you can pass a string

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guy. I found the answer:

```
String ttime = "2018-03-14T13:46:37.825Z";
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSX");
Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(ttime);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
XSDDateTime txsd = new XSDDateTime(cal);
```